# SQL query to merge the repeated values in teh output

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using different calculations in a query and combining it to get a output. The query is some what like -

```
select person_number,
sum(hours_spent),
sum(hours_amount),
hour_type,
sum(unpaid_spent),
sum(unpaid_amount),
unpaid_type
sum(total_amount_paid)
from 
(
select calc_card.hours_spent,
calc_card.hours_amount,
calc_card.unpaid_spent,
calc_card.unpaid_amount,
calc_card.total_amount_paid,
calc_card.time_card_start_date,
papf.person_id person_number 
from per_all_people_f papf,
calculations_time_spent calc_card
where papf.person_id = calc_card.person_id
and calc_card.Calculation_for = 'TimeSpent'
)
group by 
person_number,
hour_type,
unpaid_type

UNION 

select person_number,
sum(hours_spent),
sum(hours_amount),
hour_type,
sum(unpaid_spent),
sum(unpaid_amount),
unpaid_type
sum(total_amount_paid)
from 
(
select calc_card.hours_spent,
calc_card.hours_amount,
calc_card.unpaid_spent,
calc_card.unpaid_amount,
calc_card.total_amount_paid,
calc_card.time_card_start_date,
papf.person_id person_number 
from per_all_people_f papf,
calculations_time_spent DEcalc_card
where papf.person_id = calc_card.person_id
and calc_card.Calculation_for = 'ProcessedTimeSpent'
and DEcalc_card.absence_type in (select distinct absence_type from abs_table where absence_name like '%Premium%')
)
```

Now this gives me output like -

```
person_number   hours_spent     hours_amount    hour_type       unpaid_spent        unpaid_amount       unpaid_type         total_amount_paid       
1980                8               100          Manual             2                 8                  Computer               89
1980                8               100          Manual             1                 10                 Manual                 90
1980                8               100          Manual             

1981               9                60           Automatic          9                700                 Manual                10
1981               9                60           Automatic          9                700                 Manual                10
1981               9                60           Automatic       19               701                Withdrawn             10
```

Then for a person if hours_spent and hours_amount is the same and unpaid_spent, unpaid_type is same then it should only once in output. Something like -

```
person_number   hours_spent     hours_amount    hour_type       unpaid_spent        unpaid_amount       unpaid_type         total_amount_paid       
1980                8               100          Manual             2                 8                  Computer               89
1980                                              Manual            1                 10                 Manual                 90
1980                                               Manual               

1981               9                60           Automatic          9                700                 Manual                10
1981                                             Automatic                                               Manual                10
1981                                           Automatic            19               701                 Withdrawn             10
```

Can this be acheived by partition in anyway ?

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You could try using CTE's and Lag -

Example -

```
With data AS(
  YOUR EXISTING QUERY
)

,

datalagged as (
SELECT
data.*,
person_number
LAG(hours_spent,1) OVER(PARTITION BY person_number) as hours_spent_lag,
-----(for all columns you're wanting)
FROM data
)

SELECT 
person_number,
CASE WHEN hours_spent = hours_spent_lag 
     THEN '' --(or NULL) 
     ELSE hours_spent END AS hours_spent,
-----(for all columns you're wanting)
FROM datalagged;
```

The challenge here would be if your data is not cleanly sorted as shown in your example, you would need to add in an order by in the partition and in the final query, but it doesn't look like you have any key values that would make that easy.